# keyboard not recognised

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I have dual system, windows 11 and ubuntu 22.04 and my microsoft keyboard works properly with windows and doesn't work when switched to ubuntu 22.04. I already tried to install:

sudo apt install git

git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git

sudo cp linux-firmware/ar3k/AthrBT_0x11020000.dfu /lib/firmware/ar3k

sudo modprobe -r btusb

sudo modprobe btusb

sudo apt install linux-firmware/jammy-proposed

After all these actions proposed by a member here to solve the same kind of issues i hadn't any results.
I'll appreciate any help to solve this problem.

Comment: What is the Bluetooth device? Does it work? So does Bluetooth work or it can't connect a specific keyboard?

Comment: The keyboard is connected with an usb with no cables. In windows it works and in Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't work. I have a mouse connected by usb without cable and works properly in the both systems, windows and Ubuntu. The conclusion is bluetooh doesn't work with  specific device in this case a microsoft keyboard. Hope I handle to answer your questions. Thank you

Comment: Problem solved. I just reset the keyboard and it is working. Thank you